# TypeORM, many to many relation User - Animal, given User ID how to query animals

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

So I have this entities

```js
@Entity()
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    email: string

    @Column()
    name: string

    @ManyToMany(x => Animal)
    @JoinTable()
    animals: Animal[]
}

@Entity()
class Animal {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string
}
```

I want to select all animals by given User ID with take and skip. I having difficulty since there are no inverse relation on `Animal.user` entity.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using querybuilder:

```
const animals = await User.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoin('user.animals', 'animals')
      .where('user.id = :userId', {
        userId: userId,
      })
      .select(['animals'])
      .take(take)
      .skip(skip)
      .getMany();
```